# Calling a class command from another class - Python, Sublime Text Plugin

Tags: python, sublime-text-plugin

So here's the relevant code:

```
class MPzeroCVSCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    # On Save Event Handler
    def on_post_save(self, view):
        global project, cvsMsg
        if project != None or project != "None":
            if cvsMsg == None:
                view.run_command(on_mpz_load)
                #TODO: need to do this sychroneously.  (can I?)
                DoCVSCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand)
            else:
                DoCVSCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand)
```

In this event handler, I make calls to two other classes defined in my plugin, (they look different, e.g. `run_command` vs. `DCVSCommand` out of experimentation - neither works).  I have to keep each of these a separate class (in my mind) because the first - `on_mpz_load` is called via a new menu I added, and the second has to be a WindowCommand, not an EventListener.

The problem I have is how to run these classes (with instances of TextCommand, and WindowCommand respectively) from a separate class?

For those interested, here's the code: (and feel free to critic!  I'm a newb python/Sublime guy, plus I haven't finished debugging!)

```
#defaults
settings = None
project = None
cvsDir = None
cvsPath = None
cgiPath = None
docPath = None
cvsMsg = None
cvsProjDir = None

#onLoad, presents an input dialog to the user so they can state a message for cvs commits.  There is no event handler for this functionality in ST.
#this can't be a def, becuase I call it from a menu command, to set the cvs message, and also when this script gets loaded
class OnMpzLoadCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        print('here')
        self.view.window().show_input_panel("Please say what you're working on", 'e.g. reset password flow', self.on_done, None, None)
    def on_done(self, user_input):
        global cvsMsg
        cvsMsg = user_input

#gets the specific settings for the project specified
#called from a menu, so needs to be a class.
class SetCvsProjectCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, proj=[]):
        print('setting proj')
        global settings, project, cvsDir, cgiPath, cvsProjDir
        settings = sublime.load_settings('MPzeroCVS.sublime-settings')
        if proj == None or proj == 'None' :
            sublime.status_message('No project set, cvs and site will not be updated.')
        else:
            project = settings.get(proj)
            cvsDir = project.get('cvsDir')
            cgiPath = project.get('cgiPath')
            cvsProjDir = project.get('cvsProjDir')

#event handler for on_post_save event. checks if project has been set, if not, does nothing on save.  If it has, then it checks for a cvsMsg, 
#and will prompt the user to input one if he has not.  If the message is set, then does the commit/cgi  
#if no project is selected (the option is default, and available in the menu at anytime), will do nothing.
class MPzeroCVSCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    # On Save Event Handler
    def on_post_save(self, view):
        global project, cvsMsg
        if project != None or project != "None":
            if cvsMsg == None:
                view.run_command(on_mpz_load)
                #TODO: need to do this sychroneously.  (can I?)
                DoCVSCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand)
            else:
                DoCVSCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand)

#actually does the cvs commit and cgi update.  This cant be a def, becuase it needs access to the file_name, which you have to get from WindowCommand.
class DoCVSCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, view):
        global docPath, cvsMsg, project, cgiPath
        # do cvs commit
        docPath = self.window.active_view().file_name()
        #gets path for cd in cygwin
        cvsCDPath = docPath.split(cvsProjDir,1)[1] 
        cvsCDPath = cvsCDPath[2:]
        #gets file name to commit
        cvsFileName = docPath.split('MPzeroCVS',1)[1] 
        cvsFileName = cvsFileName[2:]
        #sets message in status bar
        sublime.status_message('committing your file to the '+project+' repository...')
        #does the cygwin commands TODO: fix the escaped b's in url
        cvsPipe = subprocess.Popen('C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login', stderr.STDOUT, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) #logs into cygwin
        cvsPipe.communicate(cvsDir, 500) #cd's to main sandbox (mp0 or Twili)
        cvsPipe.communicate('cd ' + cvsCDPath, 500) #cd's to folder where file is located
        cvsOutput = cvsPipe.communicate('cvs commit -m "' + cvsMsg + '" ' + docPath) #commits the file
        #sets the output of commit in status bar
        sublime.status_message(cvsOutput.stdout)

        # run cgi site update script
        sublime.status_message('running the cgi update script...')
        try:
            request = urllib2.Request(cgiPath,
                headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"})
            http_file = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=1000)
            self.result = http_file.read()
            return

        except (urllib2.HTTPError) as (e):
            err = '%s: HTTP error %s contacting API' % (__name__, str(e.code))
        except (urllib2.URLError) as (e):
            err = '%s: URL error %s contacting API' % (__name__, str(e.reason))

        sublime.error_message(err)
        self.result = False

        sublime.status_message('cvs commit and site update complete.')

OnMpzLoadCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand)
```

Comment: None of the `global ...` statements in the global scope are necessary. `global` does not not define a global variable; it indicates that a name in a local scope should be treated as a global instead.

Comment: In Python "calling a class" creates an instance of it, a major part of that process involves running its `__init__()` method, if any. If the class definition doesn't define one, the one in the base class will be invoked instead. Once an instance is created, other methods it defines can then be called (explicitly or indirectly by the framework). I think not really understanding these distinctions is a major part of your problem.

Comment: fixed the globals chepner, and Martineau, you are correct that i don't understand all the distinctions of inheritance in Python, however due to the ST framework, I can't really do this another way.  My comments in the code might help explain why I do certain things here.

Comment: My understanding of how ST works with Python is as follows: You define a "command" via  a class, and must use Command in the class name (e.g SetCvsProjectCommand).  ST takes off the Command part, and adds spaces (e.g. set_cvs_project), and this is considered a command, and that's what is called when you want to add menu items or hotkeys to do something.  When you use a class like this, you must make your class a 'child' of one of their plugin api handles. (WindowCommand, TextCommand, or EventListener), These dictate what you're doing, and provide some functionality inside your class.